# Google places API image retrieved using photo reference in the web application returning binary data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google places web service API and I am able to get the response for a place search. Using the photo reference id I am hitting the API to get the image (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=....). As this API response is (302) ie. redirected to some other url. I am getting the response in binary data. 
[image: response after redirection]
How can i use this data to append an IMG tag in my application?

encode to base64 seems to be not working. :-(

Comment: are you getting 400 ? or success ? i am guessing success

Comment: its a success. my worry is how do i use this garbage binary response data in my application

Comment: check the answer . use the value of that data directly as image source @Alexander James and dont forget to mark as accepted if its working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this directly in `img` tag that would work

collected from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078799/what-format-does-the-google-places-photos-api-return-the-image-in)

That URL returns the binary file of the image, e.g. a JPEG file. You can use that URL as the src of an  tag directly.

You can use the url directly as source

**dont make api call just use that url as source **

Comment: Tried. But its not working. in fact its not even taking the entire binary data as the img src. Maybe cz of the spaces or something.

Comment: Make sure you are processing your response correctly

Comment: @AlexanderJames use the url directly as source

Comment: yes tried using the same response as src of the img tag.
<img ng-src="{{used it here}}" />

Comment: dont make api call just use that url as source

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. Every time you show the photo you're making an API request to google to serve up the image.

Comment: @Akkuma thats the idea we dont want to load unless its needed its called lazy loading .. which in turn helps u decrease initial load time for afters page loads and better ui exprience

Comment: bro its not a place to argue .. This was a specific problem and a specific solution .. no need to go over this after years @Akkuma

Answer (score -1):

I've not checked if this is counts as an API call, but you can get the redirect url with a decent http request library in whatever programming language you use. The redirect URL is itself the actual image and you could store that and not the binary. Whether this violates the terms of service is another question entirely.